# <input/> in accordion-heading (0.11.2 vs. 0.12.0)

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

In 0.11.2 inputs in `<accordion-heading>` were possible like so:

```
<input type="text" value="Will open / close containing group on click" />
<input type="text" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" value="Will do nothing" />
```

In 0.12.0 a click into the second input seems to trigger navigation to the root page (`.../#/path` -> `.../`): http://plnkr.co/pyjENpDew621TLTb3Uom

Further investigation shows that the breaking change is [make header links keyboard accessible](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/992b23297cd100ab4e236fba469e3a70566a4163) 
How do I correctly prevent elements to toggle the accordion in the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly Hack: I ran into the same issue and ended up overriding accordion-group.html template to remove the "href" attribute.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function templateOverrides($templateCache) {
        var accordionGroupTemplate =
            '<div class=\"panel panel-default\">' +
            '   <div class=\"panel-heading\">' +
            '       <h4 class=\"panel-title\">' +
            '           <a class=\"accordion-toggle\" ng-click=\"toggleOpen()\" accordion-transclude=\"heading\"><span ng-class="{\'text-muted\': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>' +
            '       </h4>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '   <div class=\"panel-collapse\" collapse=\"!isOpen\">' +
            '       <div class=\"panel-body\" ng-transclude></div>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '</div>';

        $templateCache.put('template/accordion/accordion-group.html', accordionGroupTemplate);
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .run(['$templateCache', templateOverrides]);
})();
```

Comment: Yes, did that too, although i just placed the template in the html file:
`<script id="template/accordion/accordion-group.html" type="text/ng-template">
                <!-- template here -->
        </script>`

Comment: I ran into similar issue and you guide me to the solution, I use $templateCache.put('uib/template/accordion/accordion-group.html', accordionGroupTemplate) and remove href from original value for this template